# Confusing Query: Mixing Aggregates and Non-Aggregates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hope someone can clarify how to do this query from SQL Server 2012, or maybe what it is asking;
it seems I am being asked to do a query that combines aggregates with non-aggregates, leading to what seems like an impossible query, since one can only group by fields that appear in the `Select` clause, which messes up
the query.

I am asked to do a query on the table `Invoices`:

```
Invoices (InvoiceID, VendorID,InvoiceDate, InvoiceTotal,...)
```

I am asked to do a query that produces 6 columns:
3  columns already appear "as is" in the table: `VendorID, InvoiceDate, InvoiceTotal`

And 3 other columns are aggregates:

4) `Sum(InvoiceTotal)  AS VendorTotal`: Sum of invoices for each `VendorID`

5) `Count(InvoiceID) AS VendorCount`: Count of Invoices for each `VendorId`

6) `Avg(InvoiceTotal) AS VendorAvg`: Average of Invoices per `VendorId`

---

Now, problem is that one cannot combine in the same query (with exceptions I cannot use here) aggregates and non-aggregates unless one groups by the non-
aggregates. So I can do:

```
Select 
    VendorId, InvoiceDate, InvoiceTotal, 
    Sum(InvoiceTotal) AS VendorTotal, 
    Count(InvoiceId) AS VendorCount, 
    Avg(InvoiceTotal) AS VendorAvg 
GROUP BY
    VendorID
```

Now, I have no trouble if I only `group by VendorID`. But in order to get a
valid query, if I select either `InvoiceDate` or `InvoiceTotal` -- both non-aggregates -- I must group by each of them in order to get a valid query.

But grouping by these last two basically undoes the other aggregates: If
I group by invoice date, I lose the aggregation by Vendor, since each vendor
has different invoice dates.

I have tried doing self joins, using `Invoices AS I1 join Invoices AS I2`
and doing aggregates in `I1` and non-aggregates on `I2`, but this does not seem to work.

Am I missing something obvious here? Any Ideas?

Edit: The answer was found to be using `OVER (PARTITION BY VendorId)` , like so:

```
Select 
VendorId, InvoiceDate, InvoiceTotal, 
    Sum(InvoiceTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY VendorId) AS VendorTotal, 
    Count(InvoiceId) OVER (PARTITION BY VendorId) AS VendorCount, 
    Avg(InvoiceTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY VendorId) AS VendorAvg 
GROUP BY
    VendorID
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is what you already found, in DBMS like SQL Server 2005+ that have implemented window functions, we can use them to get aggregates `over` each `partition` while keeping the original table, so not collapsing the table as a `group by` does. I'm not writing the query here, please edit your answer.

In older versions (or other DBMS) that don't have the `OVER ()` clause syntax available, we could use `GROUP BY` in a derived table (or a CTE) and then a "self" join back to the original table, like this:

```
SELECT 
    i.VendorID, i.InvoiceDate, i.InvoiceTotal, 
    grp.VendorTotal, 
    grp.VendorCount, 
    grp.VendorAvg 
FROM
      dbo.Invoices AS i             -- our original table
  JOIN
      ( SELECT 
            VendorID,
            Sum(InvoiceTotal) AS VendorTotal, 
            Count(InvoiceId) AS VendorCount, 
            Avg(InvoiceTotal) AS VendorAvg 
        FROM 
            dbo.Invoices  
        GROUP BY
            VendorID 
      ) AS grp                      -- the aggregated table 
  ON 
      grp.VendorID = i.VendorID ;
```

Answer (score 3):

I just ran over the answer by accident, while looking at the book: We use `OVER` clause and `PARTITION BY`.

```
Select 
VendorId, InvoiceDate, InvoiceTotal, 
    Sum(InvoiceTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY VendorId) AS VendorTotal, 
    Count(InvoiceId) OVER (PARTITION BY VendorId) AS VendorCount, 
    Avg(InvoiceTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY VendorId) AS VendorAvg 
GROUP BY
    VendorID
```